# Summing salaries of employees in a new record as total of specific company

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

| Description | level | salary | code | parent company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 1 | 500 | 1234 | 1111 |
| John | 1 | 100 | 4321 | 1111 |
| Company name | 2 | null | 1111 | null |

I'm trying to sum salaries for workers and have this sum in the corresponding company record. Company and workers are connected through "*code*" and "*parent company*".

Expected output:

| Description | level | salary | code | parent company | company salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 1 | 500 | 1234 | 1111 | null |
| John | 1 | 100 | 4321 | 1111 | null |
| Company name | 2 | null | 1111 | null | 600 |

How can I put sum of salaries in company row if company and workers are connected through different columns?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output and the DBMS you're using?

Comment: added what you asked.

Comment: How do we find the company name? A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-rollup/

Comment: Your data model is non-standard, and the normal way to do this is with rollup like @jarlh has suggested.  You would sum(salary) group by userid, company with rollup and get an extra row per company with the salary that is the sum of salary there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join a subquery with the sum

```
SELECT 
  tab1."Description", tab1."level"
  ,  tab1."salary" 
  , tab1."code", tab1."parent company"
  ,tab2."salary" company_salary
  FROM table1 tab1 LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
SUM("salary") salary, "parent company" 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE "parent company" IS NOT NULL
  GROUP By "parent company" ) tab2 ON tab1."code" = tab2."parent company"
```

| Description | level | salary | code | parent company | company_salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 1 | 500 | 1234 | 1111 | *null* |
| John | 1 | 100 | 4321 | 1111 | *null* |
| Company name | 2 | *null* | 1111 | *null* | 600 |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

Comment: How can I put it under case condition that if level = 2 then add this company salary in company row?

Comment: why not add `WHERE "parent company" IS NOT NULL` a `AND "level"  = 2` there is o case needed

Comment: because I'm joining lot of tables into one big table and want that this query affect just this company salary column, so I thought that case could be good for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a window function, conditionally with respect to the description.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN Description = 'Company name'
            THEN SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY COALESCE(parent_company, code))
       END AS company_salary
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/aH8ADw4l).

**Note**: This works even if you have multiple different companies.

Comment: For me it's sum depend on description, because now I'm getting null values. If I put for example case when level = 1 it sums both values and puts it in row with level 1, if I put when level = 2 I'm getting all nulls in company salary column

Comment: Update your sample input table and expected output with some other records that conflict with the solutions proposed here. It's difficult to tell what's wrong from this side.